# Applying horizontal space between boxed minipages

Tags: spacing

I want to apply horizontal spaces between boxed `minipage`s so they would look as the image. I tried to add `\begin{flushleft}`, `\begin{center}` and `\begin{flushright}` before the `minipage`s but it doesn't work. Thank you so much for helping me.

```
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}[noframenumbering]

\fbox{%
    \begin{minipage}[t]{0.25\linewidth}
        \centering
        \textbf{GENDER}\\
        \begin{itemize}
            \item[--] Environment\\
            \item[--] Environment.
        \end{itemize}
        \begin{flushright}
            \circled{1}
        \end{flushright}
    \end{minipage}}
\pause
\fbox{\begin{minipage}[t]{0.25\linewidth} 
        \centering
        \textbf{CONSUMER}\\
        \begin{itemize}
            \item[--] Environment\\
            \item[--] Environment.
        \end{itemize}
        \begin{flushright}
            \circled{2}
        \end{flushright}
\end{minipage}}
\pause
\fbox{\begin{minipage}[t]{0.25\linewidth}
        \centering
        \textbf{TRANSPARENCY}\\
        \begin{itemize}
            \item[--] Environment\\
            \item[--] Environment.
        \end{itemize}
        \begin{flushright}
            \circled{3}
        \end{flushright}
\end{minipage}}
\pause
\vspace{1cm} 

\begin{itemize}[<+->]
    \item[\textbullet] ahdjqxbjqbxjq
    \item[\textbullet] ahdjqxbjqbxjq
    \item[\textbullet] ahdjqxbjqbxjq
\end{itemize}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `\hfill` between your minipages instead of `\pause` adds a space between your boxes while keeping then in line with each other.

Comment: THANK YOU SO MUCH. I was using `\pause` because of beamer,  `\hfill` works perfectly with it.